# JavaScript: open window with browser

Tags: javascript, window

I'd like to be able to open another window for a user and use the URL bar as if the user had used it.  This doesn't seem possible, but I might as well ask.

Basically I want to emulate the behavior of opening a new tab/window, typing some non-URL in, and having your browser behave accordingly (typically it will use your default search engine).

Can this be done with JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

What browsers do when typing a non-url in the address bar cannot be emulated e.g. using `window.open()`

Answer (score 0):

In address bar, you can enter like this to open new window

```
javascript:window.open();
```

clear the text in address bar and try this, it'll open new tab

```
javascript:showModalDialog("#","","")
```

This also will work fine, if you want to open same link in new window